# Insert Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm writing a user's guide for my software. Is there an easy way to insert keyboard shortcuts in a word document?

Here's an example of what I'd like to have in my document: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

I can probably do that manually with Shapes or Text box, but is there an easy way?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't object to switching fonts in the middle of the document, consider to download a keycap font. I found [this one](http://www.fontspace.com/byte-sized-computing/keyboard) by using search terms "keycap font" and found that it has equivalents for every key in a US keyboard.

The link points to two different fonts available and the key equivalents to get the desired key cap to appear. From what I can see, every key I'd use and many I don't have are available between the two fonts.

If the appearance is not to your liking, the suggested search terms provide other results from which to select.

[image: Control key image][image: key s image]